# console.log is not firing inside react

Tags: reactjs, next.js, axios

I am learning react and am trying to debug using console.log, but I cannot find a place to put them where they actually fire. The below function sends a data request and I want to see how the data object is formatted, but console.log will not show me anything. Any ideas?

```
// This function gets called at build time
export const getStaticPaths: GetStaticPaths<ParsedQueryParams> = async ({
  locales,
}) => {
  invariant(locales, 'locales is not defined');
  const data = await client.types.all({ limit: 100 });
  //This does not log anything.
  console.log(data);
  const paths = data?.flatMap((type) =>
    locales?.map((locale) => ({ params: { pages: [type.slug] }, locale }))
  );
  // We'll pre-render only these paths at build time also with the slash route.
  return {
    paths: paths.concat(
      locales?.map((locale) => ({ params: { pages: [] }, locale }))
    ),
    fallback: 'blocking',
  };
};
```

Comment: getStaticPaths won't be called until you visit this dynamic page in development.

Comment: This code runs on the server side and it will be visible in the terminal not in the browser.

Comment: This is exactly it. Thanks! It was on my terminal log server side. I didn't know that was a thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getStaticPaths` is run server-side, that is why you won't see anything in you web browser console. You can see the logs in you node.js output.

More information in the [Next.js documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-static-paths#when-does-getstaticpaths-run) about Static Site Generation